# if element or another_element exists in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, find, element

I have a page where both of the following elements or only the one will be visible. How can I check if any of these two elements exist? My code is for example:

```
def element_one():
   driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selector_one").is_displayed()

def element_two():
   driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selector_two").is_displayed()

if element_one() or element_two():
   print("OK")
else:
   print("ERROR")
```

Doesn't work for me if also tried `.is_displayed()` but still not working if the element_one is not visible but element_two is visible. The if or statement doesn't reach to check if element_two is displayed. Basically only checks for element_one and if it is not there then prints ERROR without checking for element_two.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @MosheSlavin Do visit [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) and help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `element_one()` and `element_two()` are not returning anything. What you want to do is something like:

```
def element_one():
   return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selector_one").is_displayed()

def element_two():
   return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selector_two").is_displayed()

if element_one() or element_two():
   print("OK")
else:
   print("ERROR")
```

Comment: Not working this way too. It doesn't reach to element_two

Comment: @bbfl Is the answer with the `try / except` statement also not working?

Comment: @bbfl add a `return` before `driver.fin...` for that answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `CSS selector` you can make it both element search in a single serach.

```
def verify_element():
   return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".selector_one,.selector_two").is_displayed()
if verify_element():
    print("PASS")
```

---

This will give you all possible options.

```
def verify_element():
   try:
      return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".selector_one,.selector_two").is_displayed()
   except:
       return False
if verify_element():
    print("PASS")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Good thinking! using `,` in the cssSelector! yet in my opinion having an `except` with no explicit error is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def element_one():
   try:
      driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selector_one").is_displayed()
   except:
      return False

def element_two():
   try:
      driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selector_two").is_displayed()
   except:
      return False

if element_one():
   print("OK")
elif element_two():
   print("OK")
else:
   print("ERROR")
```

Comment: I tried this way and it works half the way, It actually finds the element_two but then instead of OK prints the ERROR

Comment: I still get selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: for element_one if it is not visible